# Save login form data using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

[html webpage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaU1s.png)[php code shown on button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu6uh.png)[mySql database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE5yN.png)I need to store user login data. i am using phpMyAdmin. When I click on submit button, data is not stored. Instead the php code is shown. Both code files are given below. What I am doing wrong. Help me. I 
am unable to store user data using phpmyadmin in xampp.

my html code

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Yahoo Signin And Signup Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h2 style="color: midnightblue">yahoo!</h2>
     <hr color="magenta">
    <form method="post" action="connect.php" >
    <fieldset style="background:#6495ED;">
    <legend style="padding:20px 0; font-size:20px;">Signup:</legend>
    <label for ="firstName">Enter First Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First name" id="firstName" name ="firstName"> 
    <br>
    <label for ="lastName">Enter Last Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" id="lastName" name ="lastName"> 
    <br>
    <label for ="email">Enter Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" name ="email"><br>
    <label for ="password">Enter Password</label><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name ="password"> 
    <br>
    <label for ="number">Enter Mobile Number</label><br>
    <input placeholder="03---" id="number" name ="number"><br>
    <label for ="date">Enter Date of Birth</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YY" id="date" name ="date"><br>
    <label for ="gender">Enter Gender</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Male/Female/Other" id="gender" name 
    ="gender"><br>
    <br><button style="background-color:orangered;border- 
    color:dodgerblue;color:lightyellow">Signup</button>
    </fielsdet>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my `connect.php`

```
    <?php
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    // Making Connection with database

    $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','phpdata');
    if ($con -> connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed :'.$conn -> connect_error);
    }
    else{
    $stmt = $con->query("INSERT INTO signup(firstName, lastName, email, password, 
    number, date, gender)
        values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssiss",$firstName, $lastName, $email, $password, 
    $number, $date, $gender);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Sign up successful";
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
     }?>
```

Comment: share your error message.

Comment: First of all phpmyadmin is not a data storing place, phpMyAdmin supports various type of operations on MariaDB and MySQL. The main purpose of phpMyAdmin is to handle the administration of MySQL over the web, and you need to create tables on MySQL to store data in. Show us table structer if you created one

Comment: table image link is now given at the top

Comment: No error message is shown only the whole php code is shown on button click

Comment: As you are saying PHP code is rendered on webpage, please check your apache/nginx configuration. Apache need mime type "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php"  as well as "short_open_tag=On". Try debugging your PHP code first! Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Use `prepare` instead of `query`. All everything is ok.:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO signup(firstName, lastName, email, password, number, date, gender)
        values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

And make button type as submit:

```
<br><button type="submit" style="background-color:orangered;border-color:dodgerblue;color:lightyellow">Signup</button>
```

Comment: i followed everything you said but still when i click on submit button, again php code is shown

Comment: Second, you have missed or mismatch <?php ?> PHP tag. I guess I have a full working code on my local.

Comment: Please sir help me this is my mini project. Do i need to change any XAMPP setting? I used the same code you suggested with proper PHP tags.

Comment: @jkmulti give me your email id I will send u full working code.

Answer (score 0):

Add type in your submit button.

```
<button type='submit' style="background-color:orangered;border-color:dodgerblue;color:lightyellow">Signup</button>
```

and also your question marks and params ara not matching. it should be match. otherwise data won't store your db

correct that line also

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are not loading code via apache server try to open `http://localhost/signup.html` instead of `C:/xmapp/htdocs/connect.php`

It seems you want to user `PDO` but your connection string not correct

```
<?php
    $firstName = trim($_POST['firstName']);
    $lastName = trim($_POST['lastName']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = md5(trim($_POST['password']));
    $number = trim($_POST['number']);
    $date = trim($_POST['date']);
    $gender = trim($_POST['gender']);

    $con= new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=phpdata", 'root', 'root');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sqli = "INSERT INTO signup(firstName, lastName, email, password, number, date, gender)
        values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
try {
    $stmt= $con->prepare($sqli);
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$firstName);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$lastName);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$email);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$password);
    $stmt->bindParam(5,$number);
    $stmt->bindParam(6,$date);
    $stmt->bindParam(7,$gender);
    $status = $stmt->execute(); 
    echo "Sign up successful";
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error ".$e->getMessage();
} 
?>
```

another problem is with your html form button type is missing

```
<button type="submit".... />
```

Comment: OP using mysqli object oriented connection https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect

Comment: I also tried with your code but again php code is shown on button click. Button type is also submit.

Comment: screenshot links are added at the top

Answer (score 0):

here is the code, it works fine with me

```
<?php
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

// Making Connection with database

$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','phpdata');
if ($con -> connect_error) {
die('Connection failed :'.$conn -> connect_error);
}
else{

$stmt = $con->query("INSERT INTO signup(firstName, lastName, email, password, number, date, gender)
    values("'.$firstName.'","'.$lastName.'","'.$email.'","'.$password.'","'.$number.'","'.$date.'","'.$gender.'")");
if ($con->query($stmt) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$con->close();

}//end of else of connection
?>
```

Comment: i tried with your but still when i click on submit button, again php code is shown

Comment: if you are using xampp, try to write localhost in your browser and then add fields

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code after analyzing it for a lot of time. in your $stmt variable there was no query, it was empty. This code works fine just copy and paste it.

```
<?php
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

// Making Connection with database

$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','abc');
if ($con -> connect_error) {
die('Connection failed :'.$conn -> connect_error);
}
else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO signup(firstName, lastName, email, password, number, date, gender)
    values('$firstName','$lastName','$email','$password','$number','$date','$gender')";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

$con->close();



}//end of else of connection
?>
```